# Assign meaning to text (ValidID) in xtext editor

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

This might be very basic question but: how to assign meaning to text in xtext editor?

Let's say:

We have an instance of some Java object. Let's name it Data. This data object has several nested fields which contain data.

```
data.field1.value1, 
data.field1.value2, 
data.value1, 
etc...
```

Data object is created at runtime by user input and will be available when xtext based editor would try to access it.

If I write in xtext editor text like:

```
data.field1.value1
```

how to bind it to that field of data object?

To clarify: "data" object comes from outside of xtext editor but is accessible for the editor but I don't know how and where to pass it and then how to bind "ValidID" rule to its fields.

Comment: Did you have a look at xbase

Comment: I've red whole book "Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend" but there's no thing about how to accomplish what I need. Xbase is indeed explained there a bit but still I don't know how to accomplish this. Sorry. I should've mentioned about the book in the question.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit in your question

Comment: Especially about the term data object and what it actually is (a Java class .)

Comment: Ok. I'll try. I need to replace styled text widget with embedded editor in my existing rcp application. Currently there is semi-dsl used there but it is not formalized and does not have grammar defined. User has to know what to enter. User enter there "paths" in form of [data.field1.value1] in square brackets. In new xtext based editor I need to implement mapping of this text literal to real living object. "data" object is just a tree structure java object which is created at runtime by the users. It is not of any EMF type creation. In java I can retrieve object under given string path.

Comment: I have asked similar question but without reply. [link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155214/usage-of-domain-model-object-in-xtext)

Comment: Still the question. Writing data.x.y defines a y inside a x inside data or is the a data and the user says take from data x and take from data y and that data has an x and x has a y is defined somewhere else

Comment: data object has field x which is an object itself. Object x has field y. Like: person.livingaddress.streetName will mean that there is person object which has livingaddress field which in turn has streetName field and this is what should be bound to the text in editor. Ex2: car.engine.horsepower -> car has engine field. This engine has field horse power.

Comment: I am still confused Person is a class and Christian in an instance (Object)

Comment: Maybe you are searching for something like https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1722099/?srch=Jvmfield#msg_1722099

Comment: Sorry. You're right. Let me rephrase then: steve.livingaddress.streetName. "data" object is singleton and is an instance of tree-like structure.

Comment: Yes but where are all these things defined

Comment: Or does the user define ITB

Comment: ITB? What's that?

Comment: Means: is x.y.z and read operation or a define operation

Comment: ITB is a typo and should read it

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Writing x.y.z means that it exist already and I only need to read it or better: writing x.y.z represent the value in z. Defining structure of "data" is done elsewhere. Outside of xtext editor scope. Xtext need to only understand that if user will write x.y.z then it should mean field z in object y in object x which already exists. Just like public fields of pojo.

Comment: Yes but how does the editor know there is a livingadress and not a donut

Comment: So is data a map of maps. Or are it instances in a Java singleton. Or ..

Comment: Oh. Now I get you. Ok. At each level of the path I can get children as list/collection. So for steve I would get Ex1: steve. {livingaddress, wife, carCount, bankAccount, etc...} => List<DataElement>

Comment: Or let's phrase it differently. If the user would write in Java instead of dsl how would the code look like

Comment: So what about have a list of validids and simply implement content assist and validation

Comment: The alternative would be to put the dataelements into a datastructure (emf objects) that Xtext can understand and put these onto the scope

Comment: Would be interesting what "data object is created at runtime by user input" actually means

Comment: Regarding validation and content assist: This is what I have planned to do first but still xtext is too complex for me. I just think that in case of paths I should have 1:1 mapping between AST nodes and fields of "data" object. This way when doing validation I could use EMF Model which would have reference to data object field. Of course my thinking can be wrong. But I think you're an expert in this and I'll accept any help/advice from you.

Comment: I'll try to convert this "data" into structure you're talking about. Then how to add it to the scope? Where?

Comment: This is why I want to get behind the nature of the data tree and it's origin and how the user defines it

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1084135&goto=1753287&#msg_1753287

Comment: To define "data" user has a wizard where he can enter the name of the field and define where in existing structure this new field should be placed. Under which path. The type of data and value (if it is a value) can also be set at that time. Still in runtime of course.

Comment: In you case you won't parse but simply set the resources contents

Comment: Hmmm why not store the file of there uses data as hidden mydsl file and use simple cross references ?

Comment: You mean when converting to emf object structure or when adding to scope?

Comment: No I mean the persistence structure for the wizard data

Comment: Yes. It is user input from wizard so just to fill resource contents like you've said.

Comment: Yes but then you could use normal cross refs right?

Comment: Maybe. Iike I said. I'm new to xtext and I understand only a small part of it. Cross-reference is still a mystery for me.

Comment: I'd first get this running . Have a look at https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/xtext-and-dot-expressions/ for an example

Comment: I most certainly will.
But to conclude this cross-reference topic: I need to convert my existing data structure to emf object, add it to scope like you've shown me. But where this cross-reference is in here? Or this is explained in your blog?

Comment: No that is the forum link

Comment: But in a first step I'd define both the defines and the uses in the grammar

Comment: And to create eobjects programmatically use mydslfactory.einstance.createXyz()

Comment: You're a life saver.
I have already grammar ready. It was simple. I cannot put it here now since I'm out of office now. But I already have syntax/grammar defined. That is that it is in the grammar that I have [path.to.field] But I don't have defined there how to parse path.to.field to a value as I think it is not part of a grammar.